# I need help regarding grid placement on TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI for some code, and noticed that I cannot add a space or padding between these buttons, labels, and entry windows.

As you can see there is absolutely no space between where the bottom of the labels and entry windows end, and where the buttons start. Note that this is a barebones window I am trying to set up.

I've tried upping the padx and pady, changing the height, as well as changing the exact part of the grid they are on. None of these really seem to get me the thing I am looking for. The closest I could get to actually achieving what I wanted, was to create a blank entry field as padding; however, you can see why this wouldn't be good practice. You can clearly see the entry field and click on it (the one for the padding).

```py
def createAccount():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('320x109')
    window.title("Create an account")
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.configure(bg='gray')
    #Buttons
    window.create_close_button = Button(window, text="Close", command=window.destroy, pady=10)
    window.create_account_button = Button(window, text="Create")
    #Labels
    window.create_username_label = Label(window, text="Username", bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_password_label = Label(window, text="Password", bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_confirm_password_label = Label(window, text="Confirm Password", bg='gray', fg='white')
    #Entries
    window.create_username_entry = Entry(window, bd=1, bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_password_entry = Entry(window, show="*", bd=1, bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_confirm_password_entry = Entry(window, show="*", bd=1, bg='gray', fg='white')

    window.create_username_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
    window.create_username_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
    window.create_password_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
    window.create_password_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
    window.create_confirm_password_label.grid(row=3, column=1)
    window.create_confirm_password_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)
    window.create_account_button.grid(row=4, column=1)
    window.create_close_button.grid(row=4, column=2)
```

Comment: When I add `pady` to the buttons, it adds a bunch of space just as I would expect. Please show what you tried with respect to using `pady`.

Comment: [Here is with the pady](https://i.imgur.com/IEd3lnV.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show code that uses `pady`.

Comment: Edited to reflect pady changes.

Comment: I think you added `pady` to the wrong widget. If you do `window.create_close_button.grid(row=4, column=2,pady=5)`, there are proper spaces between the entry and the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method of adding spacing in a grid is to simply add a blank grid row/column label and adjust its size. Also make sure that the window is big enough to support any attempts at padding, it could be that Tkinter is just silently not performing the padding because there is no space to, particularly as you have resizing disabled.

Comment: I tried with and without resizing enabled. That label thing works, but it seems more like a hacky way of doing it. Is there any way to add a space without adding a blank label?

Comment: It does appear a bit hacky, but if you think about it, it wouldn't make much sense if Tkinter allowed you to essentially split a grid into pieces and warp parts of it by adding spacing between items. Also no I don't know of any other way of doing it.